# Create words from random characters using the sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Let's just say I have the variable `String SRand = "KELRSFGLIU"`, what I want to do is create a word from the `SRand` variable and search for that word in the database. Or looking for data in a database based on the `SRand` variable, the words that need to be found do not have to be 10 characters but can be 3, 4 - 10 characters

can this be done?

As an illustration, I want to do something like this:

Ilustration 1:

```
String SRand = "KELRSFGLIU";
String Suggestion = "";

private void Create_Suggestion(){
    //The magic for creating Sugeestion in here
    //The result can be "FIRE", "GLUE", "FUR", or something else.
    Suggestion = ???;
    SearchData(Suggestion);
}

private void SearchData(String Suggest){
    //Data Must Be Found
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: You can get all data from database and then process on that using for loop if string contains all character from word than display it.

Comment: @VrushiPatel Thank you for the suggestion, If I use your method, how many seconds does it take if I have more than 500,000 data? in my opinion if taking that much data from the database requires more than 1 second, the time will be faster when used on high-end mobile phones, but what about low-end mobile phones? while I want to check no more than 1 second if possible.

Comment: In that case you need to move you logic and database to server side , because now-a-days servers can provide you that kind of processing power.

Comment: That's a good thing and I wanted to use mariadb and let the server do the hard work, but unfortunately my application must be able to be used offline.

Comment: If that be the case I have one more suggestion in mind you can store data on local array by hard coded or store it on file which won't take that much time to load data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use trees in case you want to do that, more info can be found [here](http://exceptional-code.blogspot.com/2012/09/generating-all-permutations.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still need to study the article. If you know of or have other methods that are faster than this, I am very happy to accept it.